# Tip dialog jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, beginner, jquery-ui

How would you write this jQuery code cleaner and better? I'm a beginner.

```
$.extend({
misTip : function($tipSettings) {
    $tip = $tipSettings.tip ? $tipSettings.tip : '';
    $closeTime = $tipSettings.closeTime ? $tipSettings.closeTime : 1500;
    $refresh = $tipSettings.refresh;

    delete $tipSettings.msg;
    delete $tipSettings.closeTime;
    delete $tipSettings.refresh;

    //dialog ui tip
    var tpl = '';
    tpl += '<div style="padding:5px 20px">';
    tpl += '<p style="font-size:14px;padding-top:10px;"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span><span class="ajaxMsg">' + $tip + '</span></p>';
    tpl += '</div>';

    var $defaultTipSettings = {
        title : 'notice',
        slow : 'slide',
        width : 320,
        open : function (event, ui) {
            $(this).bind("keypress",function(event){
                $(this).dialog('close');
            });
            $dialog = $(this);
            setTimeout(function(){
                $dialog.dialog('close');
                if ($refresh) {
                    _refresh();
                }
            }, $closeTime);
        }
    }
    var $tipSettings = $.extend($defaultTipSettings, $tipSettings);
    $(tpl).dialog($tipSettings);
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using several global variables in the code, which should be local.

You are prefixing variable names with `$` for no apparent reason, that only makes the code harder to read.

You can use the `||` operator instead of the conditional operator to check for missing values.

You are using the variable `_refresh` in the code, I assume that it should be the variable that you defined instead.

```
$.extend({
  misTip : function(tipSettings) {
    var tip = tipSettings.tip || '';
    var closeTime = tipSettings.closeTime || 1500;
    var refresh = tipSettings.refresh;

    delete tipSettings.msg;
    delete tipSettings.closeTime;
    delete tipSettings.refresh;

    //dialog ui tip
    var tpl =
      '<div style="padding:5px 20px">' +
      '<p style="font-size:14px;padding-top:10px;"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span><span class="ajaxMsg">' + tip + '</span></p>' +
      '</div>';

    var defaultTipSettings = {
      title : 'notice',
      slow : 'slide',
      width : 320,
      open : function (event, ui) {
        $(this).bind("keypress",function(){
          $(this).dialog('close');
        });
        var dialog = $(this);
        setTimeout(function(){
          dialog.dialog('close');
          if (refresh) {
            refresh();
          }
        }, closeTime);
      }
    }
    var settings = $.extend(defaultTipSettings, tipSettings);
    $(tpl).dialog(settings);
  }
});
```